# Display shipping rate in product view

Tags: collection, shipping-methods, product-view

I'am using this code to get the shipping rates of the products, in the view.phtml, but I wish to only show the first item in the collection, not all of them. How could I achieve this?

**The code:** [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640917/in-magento-how-can-i-put-an-items-shipping-cost-on-the-product-page)

```
<?php
if($_product->isSaleable())
{
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('*');
$quote->addProduct($_product);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
$rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();

foreach ($rates as $rate)
{
echo $rate->getPrice();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Credits to this link is not works

Comment: I'am sorry, it is now edited to the correct link

Answer (score 1):

To access the first element of a collection:

```
 $collection->getFirstItem();
```

Although I would really recommend storing this value in an attribute for each product, and refreshing this attribute with a cron every night for example. Loading this piece of code on every product page will be very resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of simplicity dump the foreach loop, and reference the index and key:

```
echo $rates[0]['price'];
```

Messy way of doing it:

```
foreach ($rates as $rate) {
   echo $rate->getPrice();
   break;
}
```

Loading collections takes a little while, I'd certainly cache the result set at least. But Magento being Magento, you should really have a full page cache and that way the above code only has to be run once.

Comment: FPC is a way to improve a store's performance, not hide some unnecessary heavy code

Comment: Absolute rubbish, that's the primary purpose for caching, whether it is a small item thats computationally heavy or a complete html output from a collection of computationally heavy functions.

Comment: FPC should *never* be a solution for bad code. Running this on a product page, even just once, isn't a good solution if you have a way to do it more elegantly.

Comment: Of course it's not, but his code isn't bad. It's just the foreach loop that's redundant in this case, it's a computationally heavy function that needs to be stored somewhere. You're proposing adding data to the database that you've just pulled from the database, there's nothing elegant about it, normalization is there for a reason. This should be cached, you don't have to muck around with cron jobs, as you just give it a TTL, far easier.

Comment: Your logic is shocking. "Why bother ... when you can just cache it". All I am saying is, if you have a way not to run it through the frontend at all, not only you avoid slow page load times, but you also avoid potential fatal errors breaking your product page.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree to disagree. Caching is there for _resource heavy database operations_ which are always expensive. Don't get me wrong its a totally viable alternative what you propose, but I personally believe it's over-complicating a simple problem that is automatically solved by a FPC. The page is loaded once a day and cached, adding an attribute as you propose, turns into a slightly longer database response time and is called potentially 1000's of times a day. If you can provide performance benchmarks that proves your method is more efficient by all means do so.

Comment: Regardless of any cache mechanism, we are talking about accessing an attribute against loading a whole collection of rates. So the initial load (uncached) whether you use FPC or not (if you're on CE for example), is going to be quicker with an attribute. (Especially with flat catalogue on)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20612/discussion-between-adam-hall-and-mayers-dev).

Answer (score 0):

My goal was to show the cheapest shipping type available on the products. I'am using amasty's shipping per item extension, which makes an attribute with the price, and the flatrate shipping within Magento.

To achieve my goal, I created an attribute(Shipping Type) to all my products called Flatrate and Shipping per product. The flatrate attribute has the number 4752.

Then I did this:

```
// Shipping
$flatrate = array("20 €");
$amshipping = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getAmShippingPeritem());
$shippingtype = $_product->getShipping_type();

<table class="priceCalc">
        <tr>
            <td class="left">Shipping price
            </td>
            <td class="rightshipping">
             <?php 
             if ($shippingtype == 4752) {
             echo $flatrate[0]; }
             else
             echo round($amshipping).' €';
             ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

This is not the most pretty way, but so far it works.